# epitope prediction/ mapping

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, immunology

[B-CELL EPITOPE PREDICTION](http://www.sdsc.edu/pb/edu/pharm201/11/c35.pdf)

Regarding this article:

1. "Such a molecule can be synthesized or, in case of a protein, its
   gene can be cloned into an expression vector."----- is a particular
   line in this article. What does expression vector mean here??
2. "antipeptide antibodies"---- what are these?
3. "immunogenic peptides"----these are basically epitopes, am I right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. An [expression vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_vector) is a (usually circular) piece of DNA which is able to replicate inside a (bacterial) cell independently of the genome. Vectors can be transferred between bacteria and can express proteins from their own DNA sequence. They are used to express proteins inside of bacterial cells which can subsequently be purified. In this case the sequence for an immunogenic peptide is cloned into a vector and expressed in bacteria.
2. These are antibodies which are directed against a certain peptide. This is one technique of generating these antibodies. Making a (synthetic) peptide and then immunize animals against it. Then you can purify the antibodies from the serum of the animal.
3. Yes. You make short peptides of 8-12 amino acids (which is the length that the antibodies binds to) and use them for immunization.

Comment: "independently of the genome" -did not understand this term.
"Vectors can be transferred between bacteria and can express proteins from their own DNA sequence"-This line means that one bacteria can carry the gene of another bacteria and hence express the proteins of its main parent bacteria in the new parent bacteria??
"ïmmunize animals against it." - meaning the newly created antibodies are injected into the body of victim so that they can fight that particular peptide??

Comment: Can you please ask this in a new question? It is easier to answer (since pictures can be added) and it is also considered more appropriate.

Comment: I could but if i ask, it will be closed down... so whats the point?

Comment: It is basically a piece of DNA which is independent from the cells genomic DNA. Have a look at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmid#Vectors), which also contains an image.